# Edit a post without leaving the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to edit a micropost on the page without leaving the physical page.

In my app i have a page the renders all of a user's microposts using the partial below:

microposts/_micropost:

```
<%= render 'shared/edit_micropost', object: micropost %>
<%= micropost.title %>
<%= micropost.content %>
<%= micropost.url %>
<%= raw "Tags: #{micropost.tag_list.map {|t| link_to t.capitalize, tag_path(t)}}" %>
```

shared/edit_micropost:

```
<%= link_to "edit", object, remote: true %>
<%= form_for object do |object| %>
    <%= object.text_field :title %>
    <%= object.text_area :content %>
    <%= object.text_field :url %>
    <%= object.text_field :tag_list %>
    <%= object.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-mini" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click "edit" I would like the form to come up so that the title, content, url, and tag_list of the specific micropost is editable.

Right now when I click "edit" I get No route matches [GET] "/microposts/452" I'm not sure how to specify a working path in my link_to. I assume I have to move the form_for to a JS file?

I'm new to programming and would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem maybe you want to try it, '[Best in Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place)' is a jQuery based AJAX Inplace-Editor

Also there is a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) for it by Ryan Bates

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to do this would be to go ahead and render the form on the page, but hide it with javascript.  Then when the user clicks the button, show it again.  This way the form is also available to users that don't have js enabled.

Then it's just a matter of setting the `remote: true` option in the form to get it to submit via ajax and use an ajax callback to notify the user of success or failure (if you want).  Again, this approach will still allow non-js users to submit the form with a normal request, while users with js enabled will get the slick ajax functionality.

Comment: but how do you pass the variables into the form?